# "Reverse engineering" a density out of an expectation

Tags: probability, definite-integrals, expected-value

Lets say I have a random variable $X$, for which realisations are drawn from the real line, $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I know that the density of $X$ takes $\theta$ as a parameter, and I know the expectation of $X$ as a function of $\theta$

$$
\mathbf{E}_{f(\theta,x)}[X] = g(\theta)
$$

Is there anyway I can go ahead and recover the function $f(\theta,x)$ that the expectation is being taken under?  We can assume the function $f(\theta,x) = e^{x\theta}h(x\mid\theta)$ where $h$ is a probability density function (i.e., non-negative everywhere and integrates to 1).

My immediate thought was the fundamental theorem of calculus, in which the integrand of the expectation is equal  $\frac{dg(\theta)}{dz}$, but since the right hand side is not a function on $z$, this is not helpful, and just confusing.

Comment: To answer this very general question you must be more specific as to how the density depends on $\theta$. For instance if $X \sim \operatorname{exponential}(\theta)$, then $g(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}$ and we find the density to be $f(\theta,x)= \frac{1}{g(\theta)}e^{-x/g(\theta)}$. But if we instead assume $X \sim N(\theta,\sigma^2)$, where $\sigma^2$ is unknown, then it becomes impossible to recover the density, since the expectation gives no information about $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Hmm, this point, as well as the answer from Rahul, are well taken, and I suspect my problem falls into the degenerate case discussed, and will therefore require a different attack.  I will edit the question to add more detail on one of the classes of functions I'm interested, but with no further insights I will accept the current answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is possible for two different probability distributions to have the same distribution of the mean. In particular, the central limit theorem states that given enough samples, the distribution of every sample mean tends towards a normal distribution.

Specifically, if $X_1, X_2 , \dots, X_n$ are $n$ random samples drawn from a population with overall mean $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$, and if $\bar{X}_n$ is the sample mean, the limiting form of the distribution, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} {\left ( \frac{\bar{X}_n-\mu}{\sigma} \right )}$, is the standard normal distribution.

Therefore irrespective of the distribution of $\{X_i\}$, we can have the same limiting distribution of the mean.